# RecyclerView scrolls one item at a time automatically when switching between the tabs using ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I have a basic layout setup: DrawerLayout that consists of the main layout for the activity and the layout for the navigation view. The main layout has a CoordinatorLayout and all the necessary ones to implement the collapsing toolbar functionality, as well as a ViewPager which I populate with fragments later on in the code. The fragment's layout mainly consists of the RecyclerView and other minor views.

The problem is the following: whenever I scroll either of the two tabs down a little and swipe to a new tab and return back to the original one, the RecyclerView receives the onScrolled callback (which it shouldn't since I haven't scrolled the RV itself, but the ViewPager) with the negative deltaY parameter (which means the direction is upwards) which causes the next item from the top to come into visibility as a result.

A couple of notes:

- The deltaY parameter seems to be always equal to the next item's height from the top (which gives the impression that the RV scrolls one item upwards whenever this whole process happens)
- I don't set the OnPageChangeListener to the ViewPager to get notified
  whenever the page is scrolled, selected or the state was changed.
- I supply the RecyclerViewScrollListener to the fragment's RecyclerView to get notified when the RV has been scrolled to do some logic (like propagating this event to the activity to show or hide the floating action button)
- I've made a screenshot of the call stack when the onScrolled is called. Perhaps somebody might find it useful. [Take a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4NDt.png).
- I've also made a short video representing this behavior. [Take a look](https://youtu.be/4euNHnkTDXI).
- I've checked a lot of resources on the Internet, but none of them helped me to resolve this issue. Feel free to ask any questions. Any help would be much appreciated.

dashboard_activity_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="@dimen/toolbar_shadow_height">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/toolbar_padding_top"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/TitleTextView"
            tools:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dashboard_activity_content_tab_layout_height"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            tools:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/actionButtonFab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/dashboard_activity_content_fab_margin"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_search_white_24dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:useCompatPadding="true"
        tools:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"/>
```

DashboardActivity.java (relevant parts):

```
private void initViewPager() {
    mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    mAdapter = new DashboardViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mAdapter.setViewPagerId(mViewPager.getId());
    mAdapter.setRecyclerViewStateListener(mRecyclerViewStateListener);

    populateAdapter();

    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(mAdapter.getCount());
}


private void populateAdapter() {
    BaseFragment baseFragment = mAdapter.getFragmentForPosition(TAB_TAB_1);

    if(baseFragment == null) {
        baseFragment = SomeFragment.newInstance(Common.SOME_TYPE_1);
    }

    mAdapter.addFragment(baseFragment);

    baseFragment = mAdapter.getFragmentForPosition(TAB_TAB_2);

    if(baseFragment == null) {
        baseFragment = SomeFragment.newInstance(Common.SOME_TYPE_2);
    }

    mAdapter.addFragment(baseFragment);

    baseFragment = mAdapter.getFragmentForPosition(TAB_TAB_3);

    if(baseFragment == null) {
        baseFragment = SomeOtherFragment.init();
    }

    mAdapter.addFragment(baseFragment);
}


private RecyclerViewStateListener mRecyclerViewStateListener = new RecyclerViewStateListener() {


    @Override
    public void onScrolledDownwards(RecyclerView recyclerView, int deltaY) {
        // Hiding the FAB by animating it
        DashboardCommon.hideActionButton(mActionButtonFab, mViewAnimator, true);
    }


    @Override
    public void onScrolledUpwards(RecyclerView recyclerView, int deltaY) {
        // Showing the FAB by animating it
        DashboardCommon.showActionButton(mActionButtonFab, mViewAnimator, true);
    }


};
```

SomeFragment.java (relevant parts):

```
private void initRecyclerView() {
    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerViewScrollListener(this));

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(
        getContext(),
        LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,
        false
    );
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    mAdapter = new SomeRecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), mItems);

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}


// mRecyclerViewStateListener is the listener passed from the
// DashboardActivity


@CallSuper
public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
    if(mRecyclerViewStateListener != null) {
        mRecyclerViewStateListener.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
    }
}




@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int deltaX, int deltaY) {
    if(mRecyclerViewStateListener != null) {
        mRecyclerViewStateListener.onScrolled(recyclerView, deltaX, deltaY);
    }
}




@Override
public void onScrolledDownwards(RecyclerView recyclerView, int deltaY) {
    if(mRecyclerViewStateListener != null) {
        mRecyclerViewStateListener.onScrolledDownwards(recyclerView, deltaY);
    }
}




@Override
public void onScrolledUpwards(RecyclerView recyclerView, int deltaY) {
    if(mRecyclerViewStateListener != null) {
        mRecyclerViewStateListener.onScrolledUpwards(recyclerView, deltaY);
    }
}




@Override
public void onBottomReached() {
    if(mRecyclerViewStateListener != null) {
        mRecyclerViewStateListener.onBottomReached();
    }
}




@Override
public void onMidpointReached(int direction) {
    if(mRecyclerViewStateListener != null) {
        mRecyclerViewStateListener.onMidpointReached(direction);
    }
}




@Override
public void onTopReached() {
    if(mRecyclerViewStateListener != null) {
        mRecyclerViewStateListener.onTopReached();
    }
}
```

RecyclerViewScrollListener.java (relevant parts):

```
public class RecyclerViewScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {


    public static final int DIRECTION_UNSPECIFIED = -1;
    public static final int DIRECTION_UPWARDS = 0;
    public static final int DIRECTION_DOWNWARDS = 1;

    // Omitted...

    private StateListener mStateListener;




    public RecyclerViewScrollListener(StateListener stateListener) {
        // Omitted..

        mStateListener = stateListener;
    }




    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        if(mStateListener != null) {
            mStateListener.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }
    }




    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int deltaX, int deltaY) {
        if(mStateListener != null) {
            mStateListener.onScrolled(recyclerView, deltaX, deltaY);
        }

        f(deltaY > 0) {
            // Recycler view's contents are moving downwards

            // Notifying about the downwards scroll
            if(mStateListener != null) {
                mStateListener.onScrolledDownwards(recyclerView, deltaY);
            }

            // Omitted...

            if(someConditionIsTrue) {
                // Omitted...

                // Notifying the listener
                mStateListener.onBottomReached();
            } else if((someOtherConditionIsTrue) {
                mStateListener.onMidpointReached(DIRECTION_DOWNWARDS);
            }
        } else if(deltaY < 0) {
            // Recycler view's contents are moving upwards

            // Notifying about upwards scroll
            if(mStateListener != null) {
                mStateListener.onScrolledUpwards(recyclerView, deltaY);
            }

            // Omitted...

            if(someConditionIsTrue) {
                // Omitted..

                // Notifying the listener
                mStateListener.onTopReached();
            } else if(someOtherConditionIsTrue) {
                mStateListener.onMidpointReached(DIRECTION_UPWARDS);
            }
        }
    }




    public interface StateListener {

        void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState);

        void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int deltaX, int deltaY);

        void onScrolledDownwards(RecyclerView recyclerView, int deltaY);

        void onScrolledUpwards(RecyclerView recyclerView, int deltaY);

        void onBottomReached();

        void onMidpointReached(int direction);

        void onTopReached();

    }




}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I posted this question more than 2 years ago, I've decided to provide an answer. Better late than never, right?

As far as I remember, the problem was in the fact that the layout of the `RecyclerView` items had the `TextView`, which contained `android:textIsSelectable="true"` attribute. Turned out that by removing that attribute, the problem went away. How did I implement text selection then, you may ask? To be honest, I do not recall since it's been so long ago.

Anyway, if you have a problem like this, try removing the `android:textIsSelectable="true"` attribute and it may very well fix the issue for you.

Answer (score 6):

**Using This Scroll one item at a time automatically**

```
RecyclerView my_recycler_view= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(my_recycler_view);
```

**Happy Coding Cheers**

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, you saved my day!

Answer (score 3):

**Hope will help**

```
RecyclerView my_recycler_view= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();

snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(my_recycler_view);
```